# Intermittent deadlock in EntityUtils.toString()

Tags: java, http, deadlock, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm running Java 6 with HttpClient 4.1.2. I've been using code like this to reload a Guava cache. It was working well over almost a year and one day, my cache stopped reloading reliably.

**I've now narrowed the problem down to deadlock during `EntityUtils.toString()`, but I don't know why it's happening or how to avoid it.**

```
HttpEntity entity = null;
try {
  entity = PooledHttpClient.getHttpEntity(new HttpGet(location));
  // PROBLEM HERE: Deadlock occurs rarely in EntityUtils.toString()
  final String resource = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
  return resource;
} catch (Exception e) {
  // Something went wrong, log the error or retry
} finally {
  EntityUtils.consume(entity);
}
```

I had added debugging and saw that the cache stopped reloading after this method got stuck once. Here's the stack trace from a thread dump:

```
"pool-6-thread-172" prio=3 tid=0x0000000017cc4800 nid=0x862 runnable [0xfffffd7fdf1f0000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:187)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:176)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:138)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
    - locked <0x0000000735ec3cc0> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:199)
    at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:221)
    at com.something.Resource.getResource(Resource.java:216)
    ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I ve got the same problem,have you solved it?

Comment: Just added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what the issue was here and the key is is in the stack trace. In retrospect it's very obvious but I didn't understand it at the time. The code basically gets stuck at `InputStreamReader.read()` and the reason is that there's no socket timeout set (for me at least).

I had something like this:
`HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000);`

However, I missed a crucial 2nd timeout for the socket:
`HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 30000);`

Without the 2nd timeout, if the connection was made but there was an issue after that, I'd be waiting indefinitely. I was pretty puzzled here because the code in question was running in production for over a year without a single issue and then one day I started to have hourly or daily problems (fetching files some content from Heroku). Still not sure why that is, since I added the socket timeout, it's been smooth sailing!

Hope that helps!